# How to pass an array of objects as an argument in a constructor, then copy the passed array to another one (still in the constructor)

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I figured out I'd rather just show the code for this one.
So I have a class named Game right here: which contains levels. As you can see, the public constructor needs an array of `Lvl` type objects.

```
class Game {
    private:
        Lvl *_levels[10];
    public:
        Game(Lvl levels[]){
            Lvl* _levels=levels;
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
                //_levels[i]=levels[i];

                cout << endl << "i : " << levels[i].get_stage();  // DOESN'T WORK !! (compiles though)
            }
        }
};
```

And in the main, I have the following :

```
int main(){
    Lvl* lvls[10]={};

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        lvls[i]=new Lvl(0, 1, 1+i, false); // get_stage() returns the 3rd parameter
        cout << lvls[i]->get_stage();  //THIS ACTUALLY WORKS AND RETURNS THE CORRECT VARIABLE!
    }
    Game game=Game(*lvls);
}
```

So, in the main function, the array of `Lvl` objects works perfectly but for some reason, when I try to pass it as an argument to create a `Game` object, I can't use the parameter in the constructor... If I try `get_stage()`, it will return random numbers! Maybe because the array wasn't passed properly?

Anyways, guys, this is my first post on this site and I hope you'd be able to help me. maybe I'll stick around then :)
If something is unclear, feel free to ask.

Comment: With`Lvl* _levels=levels;` in the constructor you *define a local variable* with the same name as the member variable.

Comment: There are other problems, like the argument to the `Game` constructor not being the same type as the `main` variable `lvls` or the `Game::_levels` member variable. That is your cause of your current problem.

Comment: Some programmer dude Hi, thanks for your reply. Are you sure that _levels and levels are the same variable name? I usually use the underscore at the beginning of a member variable...

Comment: Also, how do I make it so the Lvl array can be passed in the Game constructor and do the right thing? I'm new to c++ and honestly, pointers really aren't my thing.

Comment: `_levels` is two different things here, and `levels` is a third.  The clash is between the local variable `_levels` and the member variable `_levels`.  Same name.

Comment: John Zwinck  Oh, I see what you mean now.. The thing is that if I remove this line : 'Lvl* _levels=levels;' it will not compile and give me an error. I'm almost positive that instead of redeclaring the same variable, '_levels' takes the first object in the 'level' array which I believe is why when I do '_levels[0].get_stage()' (first element in the array) in the Game constructor, it will actually work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main function, you have an array of `Lvl` pointers called `lvls`. When you pass the array to the constructor using,

```
Game game = Game(*lvls);
```

You're actually dereferencing a pointer pointing to the first pointer in `lvls` which happens to be a pointer to your first `Lvl` object. So your `levels` in the Constructor actually has the address of this first `Lvl` object and not the address of the `lvls` array. Since your Constructor declaration is

```
Game(Lvl levels[]);
```

`levels` is declared as a `Lvl` pointer and this makes the whole thing legal. The compiler does not throw any error.

If you wish to do the whole thing using just pointers, this is one solution,

```
class Game {
    private:
        Lvl *_levels[10];
    public:
        Game(Lvl* levels[10]){
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                _levels[i] = levels[i];
                cout << endl << "i : " << levels[i]->get_stage();
            }
        }
};
```

And then construct Game using,

```
Game game(lvls);
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Unfortunately, it does throw an error now that I haven't really had before : In constructor Game::Game(Lvl**) : expected unqualified-id before '=' token. At `_levels=levels;` Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Okay, so the thing is you can't make that assignment because `_levels` has been declared as an array of pointers and an array literal cannot be assigned to another location. You can either declare `_levels` to be a pointer to a pointer using `Lvl **_levels;`, or you can copy the pointers in `levels` to `_levels`. I have edited my answer to copy these pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You should construct the Game this way:

```
Game game(lvls);
```

Then declare that constructor like this:

```
typedef Lvl Lvls[10]; // Lvls is an array of 10 Lvl objects
Game(const Lvls& levels)
```

Then you will have a const reference to the entire array to work with, and the code you use to access it will be the same as that in `main()`.